# What is full path to the executable and the command line options

Tags: kali-linux

I ran the command to show the status of `rsyslog` service. but I don't know the executable path

Comment: Use `which command`, or `whatis command`, in extreme cases `locate command`, desperate cases make me reach for `find`.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming the command you ran to see the status for rsyslog service is `systemctl status rsyslog` ( since you haven't mentioned anything specific)

`systemctl status` should also show you the PID and executable called under `CGroup:`

Also `systemctl cat rsyslog` is a quick way to show the rsyslog systemd service file. Check what's called in via "ExecStart="

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to find the path to executables. I believe you are looking for number three below but I thought  I should mention more information.

1.You can use the `find` command to search the system. I personally like to run

`find / -name *COMMAND* 2> /dev/null` (replace COMMAND with actual command name) . This will search the entire system for the command and pass any errors to /dev/null so you do not see them. This usually gives too much information so I recommend one of the next options

2.You can use the `which` command to find the executable of almost any command. For example

```
 testUser@testMachine:~$ which cat 
 /bin/cat
 testUser@testMachine:~$ which ls 
 /bin/ls
 testUser@testMachine:~$ which rsyslogd 
 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd
```

3.If you want to see a running command/process and the options that were passed to it, then you can use `ps -ef | grep COMMAND` in order to see the process running and the options passed to it.

```
testUser@testMachine:~$ ps -ef | grep rsyslogd
syslog    1091     1  0 Mar03 ?        00:00:25 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
testUser 11359 31985  0 00:05 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto rsyslogd
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/5132 and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#ps_ax_.7C_grep_gedit .  Also note that `grep` catches the pattern _anywhere_ in an entire line, even when one uses the "do not match my pattern" trick.